# Facebook Graph API: User timezone. Does it change throughout the year?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, timezone

Does the timezone value change throughout the year to adjust to DST?

So if I query a user https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=timezone ...

Is the value returned different when I query it during summer time and winter time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That field returns the timezone offset from UTC. So yes, if the user in an area of the world that has daylight saving than it could change. For instance the East Coast goes from a 4 hour offset to a 5 hour offset when daylight saving goes into affect.

Comment: This is extremely stupid. They should return the time zone ID e.g. Europe/London, etc. Now I have no way to figure out the timezone+DST the user is on..

Comment: @KaiSellgren, in PHP you could try doing this: `timezone_name_from_abbr('', $offset, (int)date('I'));` (not fully tested, but should work in most cases)